# It is posible to change the title from a standard lwc?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-web-components, custom

I'm looking for a way to change the default title in a standard LWC called Buyer Referrals.

What I want is to show the real total of buyer referrals, not only "(3+)".

[image]

Example: If we have an opportunity with 12 buyer referrals, it is posible show in the title **Buyer Referrals (12)**?.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard components can only be modified in ways that are supported (e.g. things you can change in Setup or the App Builder). You would need to build a custom component if you want this behavior.